# Is it possible to port SSAS service of SQL Server into a docker image?

Tags: sql-server, docker, containers, ssas, windows-container

Since there is a [Microsoft container ecosystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/about/) I wonder if it is possible to port SSAS service of SQL Server into a docker image?

I know SSAS is not ported into Linux but how about windows based images?

Comment: This should be eminently possible. Power BI includes a customized version of SSAS that runs as a standalone application for its databases, for example, so it has no trouble running in such a context (albeit tied to Windows). Installing and using it in a way that complies with the license is another matter, though, and since it wasn't designed to be containerized, it might need a full Windows image.

Comment: So, from a support standpoint, no. The SQL Server team would have released an image for that, if this was the case, but as you pointed out there isn't one. In fact, the SQL Server image that exists (database only) is a Linux image and the SQL Server team has stopped investing on Windows images as they are prioritizing Linux for now. With that said, if you do find a way to deploy it, I'd say (as mentioned in the above comment) that you probably need the Server Core or Server images for that. Again, keep in mind it's not supported.